# AccessViolationException in ComputeKeys

Tags: c#, exception, indexoutofboundsexception, anycpu

*Firstly I apologise if this, to you, is obviously a hardware issue, and not a programming issue.  If it is, hopefully we can migrate it to the appropriate place.*

I have a long-running web-services program (Any CPU), which has a whole bunch of data repositories that are held in-memory.  Some are refreshed every hour, others less often.  Some of these repositories sort the data (simple POCOs) after retrieving them from 3rd party sources.

Once in a blue moon, I get an `AccessViolationException` within the method `ComputeKeys` during a `Sort`.  Some of these repositories use `List<T>.Sort` after getting the data from the 3rd party sources.

The code that is performing these sorts is trivial and depends on the repository, but here are two examples:

```
pocos.Sort((a, b) => a.BookingDate.CompareTo(b.BookingDate));
```

or:

```
pocos.Sort((a, b) => a.Date.CompareTo(b.Date));
```

Note that these data-sets are quite big (comparatively).  One has over 140,000 elements.  I log exceptions to a database, and this is the log I have (The times correlate to another log I have that shows a repository was finishing fetching data at the time):

```
Time              Host  Data
05/11/2014 16:50  HOST2 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:50  HOST2 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:38  HOST2 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:29  HOST2 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:26  HOST2 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:23  HOST2 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:21  HOST2 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:19  HOST1 {"Name":"IndexOutOfRangeException","Method":"Dispose","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Index was outside the bounds of the array.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Dispose"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:15  HOST1 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:14  HOST1 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:09  HOST1 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 16:08  HOST1 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 15:58  HOST1 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
05/11/2014 15:57  HOST1 {"Name":"AccessViolationException","Method":"ComputeKeys","Source":"System.Core","Message":"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.","StackTrace":{"Lines":[{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ComputeKeys"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Sort"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"MoveNext"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":".ctor"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"ToList"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"lambda_method"},{"LineNumber":0,"Method":"Execute"}]}}
```

As you can see, it occurred at about the same time ON BOTH HOSTS.  Hence me wondering if this is not a .NET/programming issue - but a hardware one.  Note they are both VMs and apparently build in the same manner.  Both processes on the separate hosts died a death (we load-balance between the hosts).

Repository Refreshes are done using a `System.Threading.Timer`.  However, looking at my repository logs, no repository refreshes LESS than an hour, and the longest repository to refresh, is 11 minutes - so there is no overlap.

Access to the data is protected using a `ReadWriterLockSlim` class.  I know this is a bit obscure, and if anyone needs any additional information I'll be happy to provide what I can.

Comment: Possible that VMWare memory ballooning is your issue? Anything telling in your logs on the ESX host?